# Fetch single data from table in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables in my SQL Server

1.) Registration it's columns

```
   Reg_Id     bigint, primary key and auto increment
   Name       nvarchar(50),
   Tranx_id   nvarchar(30),
   Email      nvarchar(30),
   Username   nvarchar(30),
   Password   nvarchar(30),
   Edition_Id nvarchar(50),
   Default_Id nvarchar(50),
   Reg_Date   datetime,
   usertype   nvarchar(50),
```

2.) AllEditionPages it's columns

```
Page_id       bigint, primary key and auto increment
edition_date  datetime,
noofpages     int,
Page_no     int,
image_path  nvarchar(50),
Active   int,
type_of_page  varchar(50),
Image_Width  int,
Image_Height int,
```

3.) Edition

```
id  int, primary key and auto increment
edition_date  datetime,
noofpages  int,
XMLFile  nvarchar(50),
PDFFile  nvarchar(50),
PDFPrefix nvarchar(50),
type   nvarchar(50),
price  nvarchar(50),
reg_req nvarchar(50)
```

As per above table I try below sql query

```
    SELECT edi.*, aep.*, reg.*
    FROM Edition as edi INNER JOIN Registration as reg 
    ON edi.id = reg.Edition_Id INNER JOIN AllEditionPages as aep
    ON edi.edition_date = aep.edition_date
    where reg.Edition_Id= edi.id
    and reg.Reg_ID = 14
```

From this query I get this output:

```
id    edition_date              type    price  page-id

96    2012-07-18 00:00:00.000   free    null    2503
96    2012-07-18 00:00:00.000   free    null    2503
```

I get in output two rows, but want only single row in output

Comment: And which row do you want to have?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `common table expression` in this scenario in following way:

```
 WITH cteTable AS
    (
        SELECT edi.*, aep.*, reg.*
        FROM Edition as edi INNER JOIN Registration as reg 
        ON edi.id = reg.Edition_Id INNER JOIN AllEditionPages as aep
        ON edi.edition_date = aep.edition_date
        where reg.Edition_Id= edi.id
        and reg.Reg_ID = 14
    )
    select top 1 * from cteTable
```

As you two table contains edition_date, you need to spcify the column name instead of using "*" in following way:

```
WITH cteTable AS
    (
        SELECT edi.id,edi.edition_date,edi.noofpagez,edi.XMLFile,edi.PDFFile ,edi.PDFPrefix,edi.type,edi.price,edi.reg_req ,
        aep.Page_id, aep.edition_date,aep.noofpages,aep.Page_no,aep.image_path,aep.Active,aep.type_of_page,aep.Image_Width,aep.Image_Height,
        reg.Reg_Id,reg.Name,reg.Tranx_id,reg.Email,reg.Username,reg.Password,reg.Edition_Id,reg.Default_Id,reg.Reg_Date,reg.usertype
        FROM Edition as edi INNER JOIN Registration as reg 
        ON edi.id = reg.Edition_Id INNER JOIN AllEditionPages as aep
        ON edi.edition_date = aep.edition_date
        where reg.Edition_Id= edi.id
        and reg.Reg_ID = 14
    )
    select top 1 * from cteTable
```

Comment: i get error 
    `Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
    The column 'edition_date' was specified multiple times for 'cteTable'.`

Comment: @everwhere: since that column `edition_date` appears in more than one table, you need to **explicitly define** the list of columns you want - don't just do a `SELECT edi.*, aep.*, reg.* ` - **say** which columns you really need!

Comment: @everwhere : As marc_s told, you need to specify your column name to get rid of this ambiguity error.....

Comment: want to match for this reg_id in my table and i need edi.id, aep.image_path, reg.Reg_ID in output

Answer (score 0):

You can use select distinct if the 2 rows have the same value, or you can simple use `LIMIT 0,1` behind your query.

Comment: This question is about MS SQL Server, and `LIMIT 0,1` doesn't work there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify one row.From your putput it looks like you have duplicate data and if that is the issue you should use distinct to get distinct rows..Otherwise specify what exactly you need.